# What does "symmetric about the origin" mean?

Tags: graphing-functions

What does it mean when a graph or a point on the Cartesian plane is symmetric about the origin or with respect to the origin?

Comment: Have you [searched](http://www.mathwords.com/s/symmetric_origin.htm) for an answer yet?

Comment: Take a point, rotate it around the origin by 180 degrees.  It there is another point exactly there, that point is symmetric around the origin.  The same exercise works for functions and relations.

Answer (score 3):

That $f(-x)=-f(x)$ for all $x$.

Geometrically, this means that if you reflect the graph of $f$ about one axis and then the other, the graph will land back on top of itself (i.e., you'll get the original graph again).

Same idea with a point $P(x,y)$: $Q(-x,-y)$ would be the corresponding point symmetric about the origin.